# javascript subscribe form change

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code for form output, but I want to change the result so that it will load two buttons which will subscribe and unsubscribe, how do I do that?
Tried

```
<div><a onclick="$('div#newsletter_message').load('index.php?route=module/newsletter/callback&subscribe=' + $('input[name=\'subscribe\']:checked').val(1) + '&email=' + escape($('input[name=\'newsletter_email\']').val()) + '&name=' + escape($('input[name=\'newsletter_name\']').val()), function() { $('div#newsletter_message').hide(); $('div#newsletter_message').show('slow'); });" class="buttons"><span style="float:left; clear:both;">Subscribe</span></a></div>
```

and

```
<div><a onclick="$('div#newsletter_message').load('index.php?route=module/newsletter/callback&subscribe=' + $('input[name=\'subscribe\']:checked').val(0) + '&email=' + escape($('input[name=\'newsletter_email\']').val()) + '&name=' + escape($('input[name=\'newsletter_name\']').val()), function() { $('div#newsletter_message').hide(); $('div#newsletter_message').show('slow'); });" class="buttons"><span style="float:left; clear:both;">Unsubscribe</span></a></div>
```

But no effect

```
<div class="box">
  <!-- <div class="box-heading"><?php echo $heading_title; ?></div> -->
  <h3><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h3>
  <div class="box-content">
    <div id="newsletter_message" class="content" style="display:none; background: #FFFFCC; border: 1px solid #FFCC33; padding: 10px; margin-top: 2px; margin-bottom: 15px;"></div>
    <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" id="module_newsletter" name="module_newsletter">
      <div style="text-align: left;">
        <span class="required">*</span><b><?php echo $entry_email; ?></b><br />
        <input style="width:90%;" type="text" name="newsletter_email" required placeholder="<?php echo $entry_email; ?>"/><br />
        <?php if ($name == 'optional') { ?>
        <b><?php echo $entry_name; ?></b><br />
        <input style="width:90%;" type="text" name="newsletter_name" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_name; ?>"/>
        <?php } elseif ($name == 'required') { ?>
        <span class="required">*</span><b><?php echo $entry_name; ?></b><br />
        <input style="width:90%;" type="text" name="newsletter_name" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_name; ?>"/>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="" />
        <?php } ?>
        <br />
        <input name="subscribe" value="1" type="hidden" />
      </div>
      <table style="align:left;">
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 100%;">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" style="vertical-align: middle;" id="subscribe" name="subscribe" value="1" checked="checked"/><label style="font-size:10px; vertical-align: middle;" for="subscribe"><?php echo $text_subscribe; ?></label></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" style="vertical-align: middle;" id="unsubscribe" name="subscribe" value="0" /><label style="font-size:10px; vertical-align: middle;" for="unsubscribe"><?php echo $text_unsubscribe; ?></label></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <div><a onclick="$('div#newsletter_message').load('index.php?route=module/newsletter/callback&subscribe=' + $('input[name=\'subscribe\']:checked').val() + '&email=' + escape($('input[name=\'newsletter_email\']').val()) + '&name=' + escape($('input[name=\'newsletter_name\']').val()), function() { $('div#newsletter_message').hide(); $('div#newsletter_message').show('slow'); });" class="buttons"><span style="float:left; clear:both;"><?php echo $button_go; ?></span></a></div>

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That code is very hectic to read. You should use click event handlers in jQuery rather than inline onclick attributes. Hello 1998.

Comment: guess you are right, I should refactor it, need to improve my js though.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this...

```
$('input[name=\'subscribe\']:checked').val()
```

With this...

```
$('input[name=subscribe]:radio:checked').val()
```

You need the `:radio` selector as you also have a hidden form input with the same name. Bear in mind what this fact may do to your form for non-javascript users.

Comment: well it still doesn't work, guess I need to improve in js. Can you help me to get the right result?

Comment: @fob I've added a new answer with a more thorough example.

Comment: well I needed to make it without radio selector just 2 buttons - subscribe and unsunscribe. It's actually a tpl file of subscription module. Very old though but working.

Answer (score 0):

As requested, here is a more thorough answer. I can't help you fix all your code, as that is outside of the scope of Stack Overflow, however here is something to help you get started.

Basic working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jeb2x/

Let's say you have a form...

```
<form id="SubscribeForm">
    <input type="radio" name="subscribe" value="1" checked="checked" />
    <input type="radio" name="subscribe" value="0" />
    <a href="#" id="alert">Alert selected value</a>
</form>
```

You can subscribe to the click event of the link with id `alert` and have it alert the selected radio button value. This Javascript code should be in a separate file to your html, and included in the head using a script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/pathtofile/scripts.js"></script>
```

...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#SubscribeForm').on('click', 'a#alert', function(){
        var selectedValue = $('input[name=subscribe]:checked').val();
        alert(selectedValue);
    });
});
```

There are a few principles you need to learn about in order to understand the code here.

Firstly, it is subscribing to the `ready` event of the document. This ensures that the code only runs when the DOM has finished loading, and therefore, your form is definitely ready to be used. There is also a shorthand way of subscribing to document ready, which is to pass an anonymous function to jQuery, and it knows to run it on DOM ready

```
$(function(){
    //...code here
});
```

It is then subscribing to the `click` event of the form. This code uses a principle called event delegation, which is worth reading up on. It's not really needed for this simple example, but is advantageous if you need to bind to multiple events within the same div for example. The code could in this case be simplified to...

```
$('a#alert').on('click', function(){
    var selectedValue = $('input[name=subscribe]:checked').val();
    alert(selectedValue);
});
```

...or even just `$('a#alert').click(function(){`

The code then uses my original solution (minus the `:radio` selector, which isn't needed as there is only one group of inputs with the name 'subscribe'), to alert the selected value.

In your case, you are trying to call an external script in order to subscribe or unsubscribe users. One way to do this is to use an AJAX request. You could use any of a number of methods to do this. You are using the `load` method above, which will send a request to the url supplied, and insert the response into the selected element.

```
$("#result").load( "test.html" );
```

In the example here, the response from test.html will be inserted into the element with id `result`. If you wanted to do something more complex with the response, you could use one of jQuery's AJAX methods, such as `$.ajax()` or `$.get()`

Hope this helps :)